# Has the Doctor ever snapped his fingers to open the TARDIS since early series 5?

Tags: doctor-who, tardis

When The Doctor first meet with River Song, she pretended he could open the TARDIS by snapping his fingers :

> [...] But not "my" Doctor. Now my Doctor, I've seen whole armies turn and run away. And he'd just swagger off, back to his TARDIS. And open the doors with a snap of his fingers. The Doctor. In the TARDIS. Next stop: Everywhere.
>
> -Professor River Song, Doctor Who, series 4 episode 9 *Forest of the Dead*

He successfully did it shortly after that and he also did it in [the first episode of series 5 *The Eleventh Hour*](http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/The_Eleventh_Hour). But I don't remember him doing so recently. Did I miss something or he just *forgot* he could do it?

Comment: In *The Day of the Doctor*, Clara *closes* the TARDIS door from the inside by clicking her fingers, near the start of the episode. Commencing furious speculation in three, two, one...

Comment: I remember he did it in "Day of the Moon" when it was invisible, standing in his cell.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> In the 2008 episode "Forest of the Dead", River Song (a character whose timeline intersects with the Doctor in reverse order) says to the Doctor that she knows he would be able to open the TARDIS doors with a snap of his fingers. Although the Doctor dismisses this as impossible, at the conclusion of the episode, he opens and closes the doors by doing just that, eschewing the need for a key.
>
> The Eleventh Doctor also does this at the end of "The Eleventh Hour", when revealing the newly regenerated TARDIS interior to Amy Pond; **he then does it again in "Day of the Moon".  In the 2011 episode, "The Doctor's Wife", he tries to open it by snapping his fingers, but the door is locked by the mysterious entity, House.** This ability seems to be unique to the Doctor, though, as he said Time Lords cannot do that.

[From Wikipedia on TARDIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TARDIS)

Comment: It's not unique to the Doctor. Clara did the same at the beginning of " The Day of The Doctor". Aaaaand I just saw the date of this answer...nevermind...(or update it, whatever)

Answer (score 3):

He opened the TARDIS with a snap of his fingers in early Season 6, as well - either *The Impossible Astronaut* or the second part.

Answer (score 0):

Three years later, it's still a thing. He does it at the end of Hell Bent (final episode of season 9)